# I'm successfully running a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B as a WiFi access point, but I cannot connect to the internet through the Pi itself?

Tags: access-point

Good day all!

I was following this method of turning my Raspberry Pi Model 3 into a WiFi access point:

["How to use your Raspberry Pi as a wireless access point"](https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/)

...and it is now working successfully.

The internet connection is provided by a 4G/LTE router connected to eth0 on the Pi and I can connect to the Pi WiFi access point using my phone then browse the internet with no issues so far.

However, I have run into a slight problem in that I cannot access the internet from the Pi itself, like when I try to use the browser it simply cannot open any pages.

I was looking to remotely control the administration of the Pi access point through AnyDesk so I cannot do that, and I imagine any alternative methods of remote access wouldn't work either simply because the Pi cannot connect to the internet.

Looking for some help with this issue, thank you to everyone in advance for your time and effort.

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/112673/edit) your question and add the output of these commands to it: `ip addr` and `ip route`.

Comment: on the pi itself, what DNS server is it using? Is it doing DHCP or static? I'm suspecting it's static IP in which case you probably have specified the DNS server yourself.

Comment: Also `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.