# Wireless access point, I can connect to the pi, but I can't access the internet, and the pi cannot detect any routers

Tags: access-point

I can't connect to the internet on the pi itself and I cannot connect to the internet through the pi.

But the pi shows up on my phone when I search for access points, I can even connect to it with the password, but the internet won't work.

When I click on the two blue arrows pointing up and down in the top right it says "no wireless interfaces found." when I hover over it with my mouse it says:

"eth0: Link is down

wlan0: Associated with

wlan0: Configured 192.168.4.1/24"

I used this tutorial https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

I found a similar question with no answer here [I'm successfully running a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B as a WiFi access point, but I cannot connect to the internet through the Pi itself?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/112673/im-successfully-running-a-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-as-a-wifi-access-point-but-i)

some comments said to post command outputs, so here is a link to the three commands they asked for https://i.stack.imgur.com/i71Qw.jpg

Any tips?

Thank you

Comment: I gather internet access should be via eth0, and since `eth0: Link is down`, there's your issue - do you have a cable connecting it?

Comment: Please execute the following commands on the command line and add its output to your question: `ip addr` and `ip route`.

Comment: @Ingo I have those commands in the imgur image

Comment: @JaromandaX does it have to be connected through ethernet?

Comment: @JaromandaX I plugged in ethernet and it changed to eth0: configured 169.254.85.66/16, but I still can't connect

Comment: the instructions you followed show the pi access point as having one wired and one wireless interface - yes, of course you have to connect ethernet - unless you have a second wifi interface that connects to some other wireless access point for internet access - which you don't - basically, one interface for your AP, the other interface connects to the internet,  - I suggest you re-read that tutorial and don't skip bits

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm sorry, I missed that part at the begining.

I reread the steps and even redid them, except for the ones that required an internet connection.

I plugged in an ethernet cable and it's still not connecting, like I mentioned in another comment  it changed to eth0: configured 169.254.85.66/16

Comment: what ARE you connecting to on the ethernet port? either something wrong with the cable, or the device you are plugging into - do you have a DHCP server the pi can get an IP address from on the ethernet port? or perhaps you need to set a static IP on the ethernet port?

Comment: @JaromandaX I found the problem, I plugged it into the wrong ethernet port. there was a light on the pi to turned on so I thought it was correct.

thank you, I'm sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 2):

To have a decent answer here is the solution the questioner stated in a comment:

> I found the problem, I plugged it into the wrong ethernet port. there was a light on the pi to turned on so I thought it was correct.